# Count Number of Queries Each Page Load with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm specifically looking to extend the `PDO` object somehow to add an internal counter every time a query is executed.  I want to do this in a way were I wouldn't have to change any of my existing queries or add an extra function [like this suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290867/count-number-of-mysql-queries-executed-on-page).

I not that familiar with classes or the PDO class in particular, but could this be done?  How would I go about this?

I'm thinking extend `query` and `execute` and increment a stored variable each time they're called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extending `PDO` would be done like any other class. Would this suit your needs? The only other code change would be having to instantiate this class instead of the `PDO` class when making your initial connection.

```
class PDOEx extends PDO
{
    private $queryCount = 0;

    public function query($query)
    {
    // Increment the counter.
        ++$this->queryCount;

    // Run the query.
        return parent::query($query);
    }

    public function exec($statement)
    {
    // Increment the counter.
        ++$this->queryCount;

    // Execute the statement.
        return parent::exec($statement);
    }

    public function GetCount()
    {
        return $this->queryCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works nicely! Just what I was looking for. Though, I changed `exec` to `prepare`.  I think that will capture all my uses.

Comment: Can this be implemented somehow to account for `PDOStatement` as well?

Comment: If your PHP version is >= 5.10 and you are surcharging `prepare`, you should change `public function prepare ($sql, $options = NULL)` to `public function prepare ($sql, $options = array())`

Answer (score 0):

Just execute:

```
SHOW PROFILES;
```

The greatest `Query ID` is what you are after. This will also give you information about the last 15 (default) query execution time.