# How to count how many queries on page load?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I used this simple following function for my SQL select query:-

I want to be able to count how many queries is being executed when running this function? If this function has been called 10 times then it will be calling SQL query 10 times. How can I output this as string? I tried using

```
count($sql);
```

but this produces..

```
1111111
```

Which means 7 times, when I try use

> array_sum()

it doesn't add all the ones..
any help with this please?

many thanks

```
public function select($rows = '*', $table, $where = null, $order = null, $limit = null, $echo = null) {
    $sql = "SELECT ".$rows." FROM {".$table."}";
    if($where != null) {
        $sql .= " WHERE ".$where;
    }
    if($order != null) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY ".$order;
    }
    if($limit != null) {
        $sql .= " LIMIT ".$limit;
    }
    if($echo != null) {
        echo $sql . '<br />';
    }
    //echo $sql . '<br />';
    echo count($sql);           
    return $sql;
}
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/12850886/763468

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to wrap your SQL queries into class/function and plant accounting there. Then you just need to init your counter as very first thing in your script. Increase counter on each query. Display counter at the end of your scripts.

But in your case, if your return string "1111" means 4 queries (like each character means single query), then just do ordinary `strlen()` on that string and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

you can use static variable inside your function and increase it each time.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with a static variable that can be accessed within and outside the function.

```
public function select (...) {

    static $count_sql;

    [your function code]

    $count_sql++;

}
```