# How to view how many MySQL queries ran on page load

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm testing performance on a CMS I'm making, and I'm wondering is it possible to view what queries were ran on a page load. For example, let's say I run 'test.php'. When I go to it, a list of queries ran by mySQL show at the bottom of the page - is this possible? I've seen sites do this before.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290867/count-number-of-mysql-queries-executed-on-page

Answer (score 2):

The function `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` will show the real-time and past history of all processes.

[`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-processlist.html)

If you are using a server on which you have the rights to install packages, you can install **`mysqltop`** and test in real time file and MySQL resource usage and queries.

Comment: Thank you for editing a grammar. I'm from Croatia and should be improve english grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if all your queries go through a function then it should be easy, but if each only uses the standard call, then it won't be. This also let's you switch to a different database type or something like that easily.

For instance on the CMS's I modified to be a library program, I have a DB Query function:

```
function db_query($qstring, $conn) {
$dbh = mysql_db_query($dbname,$qstring, $conn);
// this is where I would add some incrementing code, but it has to be global.
// or just do something like 
if($_GET["debug"]=="debuginSQLcount"){    
    echo $qstring
}
return $dbh;
}
```

then to use it, I just do something like

```
$sql = "SELECT stuff";
}
$result = db_query($sql, $link);
if (!$result || db_numrows($result) < 1) {
```

If you do it like this, then just add a line to the function which increments a $GLOBALS variable or something like that. Read more at [PHP global or $GLOBALS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573847/php-global-or-globals)